# How to populate a datagridview combobox from mysql - vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview(with 5 columns: 4 textbox and 1 combobox) and it loads data in there from mysql. This is the code I used, when I tried it in all textbox column, it works fine. But when I change the last column into a combobox, I got an error saying:

"The following exception occured in the DataGridView:

System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event."

```
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=12345;database=db_scheduling"
    teacherQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_teacher ORDER BY id")
End Sub

Sub teacherQuery(ByVal strings)
    Try
        Dim sqlcommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", AddTeacher.txt_AddTeacher_ID.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", AddTeacher.txt_AddTeacher_Lname.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", AddTeacher.txt_AddTeacher_Fname.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", AddTeacher.txt_AddTeacher_Mname.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject_to_teach", AddTeacher.cmb_AddTeacher_Subject.SelectedItem)
        Dim Table As New DataTable
        With sqlcommand
            .CommandText = strings
            .Connection = sqlconn
        End With
        With sqladapter
            .SelectCommand = sqlcommand
            .Fill(Table)
        End With

        '----HERES THE PROBLEM-----'
        datagrid_Teacher.Rows.Clear()
        For x As Integer = 0 To Table.Rows.Count - 1
            datagrid_Teacher.Rows.Add(Table(x)("id"),
                                      Table(x)("lname"),
                                      Table(x)("fname"),
                                      Table(x)("mname"),
                                      Table(x)("subject_to_teach"))
        Next
        '---------------------------'

        'Bold header
        With datagrid_Teacher.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle
            .Font = New Font(datagrid_Teacher.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

EDIT: The problem in here is adding data in the datagridview (combobox (subject_to_teach column))

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the datagrid_Teacher.Rows.Add way:

```
datagrid_Teacher.Datasource = Table;
datagrid_Teacher.Databind();
```

Alternatively add this on your code (event handler for Gridview Dataerror):

```
private void ctrldataGridView_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
       {
          //do nothing
       }
```

Comment: tried it and it just loads data into datagridview textbox.

Comment: I don't get an error but it doesn't load the data from mysql (only in the combobox column)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by removing the combobox column in design and add the combobox column in code, and modified my code into this:

```
Sub teacherQuery(ByVal strings)
    Try
        Dim sqlcommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", AddTeacher.txt_AddTeacher_ID.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", AddTeacher.txt_AddTeacher_Lname.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", AddTeacher.txt_AddTeacher_Fname.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", AddTeacher.txt_AddTeacher_Mname.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject_to_teach", AddTeacher.cmb_AddTeacher_Subject.SelectedItem)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "" + txt_TeacherSearch.Text + "%")
        Dim Table As New DataTable
        With sqlcommand
            .CommandText = strings
            .Connection = sqlconn
        End With
        With sqladapter
            .SelectCommand = sqlcommand
            .Fill(Table)
        End With
'---THIS IS WHAT I ADDED
        Dim combo As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        Dim row As DataRow

        With combo
            For Each row In Table.Rows
                .Items.Add(row.Item("subject_to_teach").ToString)
                .Name = "Teaching Subject"
            Next
        End With
        datagrid_Teacher.Columns.Add(combo)
'-----------------------
        datagrid_Teacher.Rows.Clear()
        For x As Integer = 0 To Table.Rows.Count - 1
            datagrid_Teacher.Rows.Add(Table(x)("id"),
                                      Table(x)("lname"),
                                      Table(x)("fname"),
                                      Table(x)("mname"),
                                      Table(x)("subject_to_teach"))
        Next

        'Bold header
        With datagrid_Teacher.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle
            .Font = New Font(datagrid_Teacher.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

and this

```
Private Sub datagrid_Teacher_DataError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles datagrid_Teacher.DataError
    'ERROR HANDLER
End Sub
```